# -PHP Regular expression or strpos() in my condition?

Tags: php, regex, strpos

My question is:

**Input:** Thousands abbreviated message.

**Output:** Filtered message

**Filter:** ( (message has Alarm) or (message has Emergency) ) and (message has not Restore)

**Examples:**

1. Ur001 General User Opening By User   (True)
2. Panic Zone Alarm Security System Zn2 Zone 2 Name  (False)
3. Keypad Panic Emergency Security System Ur1 Uer 1 Name   (False)
4. Keypad Panic Emergency Restore Security System Ur1 Uer 1 Name   (True)

I know there are bunch of similar question in their conditions.  Which way is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your search terms are known (`"Alarm"`, `"Emergency"`, `"Restore"`) regexes are a poor choice. You should use `strpos` (or `stripos` to ignore capitalisation) for this.

That being said, if you want to search for those words as actual words and not as substrings (ie. you want `"Restored"` to NOT trigger the `"Restore"` match, then you have no choice but to use Regex. In this case, put `\b` before and after the word to find them. Something like this:

```
if(preg_match("/\b(?:Alarm|Emergency)\b/i",$str) && !preg_match("/\bRestore\b/i",$str))
```

Remove the `i` modifier if you speicifcally want that capitalisation.

Comment: Thank you! Very very much!!! Your answer is so clearly!  I think I will choose stripos() this time. Because input message is formated by remote hardwares. Restored and Restore has same meaning. Thank you again! I Like you!